# asynchronous handleResponse invoked twice for single webmethod request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous, cxf-client

I have developed a asynchronous JAX-RS web method using Apache CXF API. The webmethod takes a custom type as parameter as in

```
 @POST
 @Path("/query")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(value={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON , "application/CustomType"})
 public void getQueryResults(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,    CustomType conf)
```

I had implemented(Service as well as Client side) a Custom MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter to take care of serializing my 'CustomType'.
On the Client side i ergister the imlpemented ones as

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(CacheConfigReader.class).register(CacheConfigWriter.class);
```

I make a async request to the service that has

```
asyncResponse.resume(result); // result is a string
```

On the client

```
Future<String> future = asyncInvoker.post(entity, String.class);
```

My observation is that randomly the response is empty though on the server logs am able to see non-empty result. upon debugging i find that there are two threads that invoke

```
 JaxrsClientCallback . handleResponse()
```

One of them with the actual result and another empty. Based on what executes first the result is the actual string or empty. The trace of the call contains invocation from phase interceptor chain. 
This occurs only when i register the client with Custom reader  and writers. When I set the request body with a json only one thread handles the response.
Can someone shed light on why the addition of MessageBodyReaders / Writers causes this issue ?